# c# retrieve data like e.g. in jquery

Tags: c#

I have build a webbrowser and retrieve the content of a page...

But now its pretty strange to cut the source X times.

What I want to achive is fill a `ListView` with some Data. Here is a Sample-Table that contains some data I need.

```
<div id="hostsindex">
  <div class="right-actions folder-tab">
    <a href="/.../.../">Details</a> -
    <a href="/../../...html">Add</a>
    - <a href="/../.../.....html">Update</a>
  </div>
  <table class="glossy">
    <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="3">Services</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="40%">Hostname</th>
        <th width="30%">Service</th>
        <th>Info</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notranslate">
        <td><a href="/.../.../foo.bar.org">foo.bar.org</a></td>
        <td>Host</td>
        <td>11.222.333.444</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="notranslate">
        <td><a href="/.../.../hello.world.org">hello.world.org</a></td>
        <td>Host</td>
        <td>555.666.777.88</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to select all `<tr class="notranslate">` inside the `<div id="hostsindex">`.

So in the end I want an array filled with the `tr`'s

at the moment my source gets cut several times but I was wondering if there is something like a selector or querySelector for webbrowsers in C#?

Or is there a way to do a select of elements on a allready selected element ?

Sample

```
HtmlElementCollection data = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hostsindex");
//now do some query/selection on data ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) it's also available directly in Visual Studio through NuGet.  You can get the entire pages HTML into a HTMLDocument object, then pull back any collections you wish.

For example:

```cs
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("notranslate"));
```

Where htmlDoc would be your HTMLDocument object.  You can then loop through the "nodes" collection and manipulate as you wish.

Comment: Actually I never heard about it. I will truly give this a try and will come back to tell you if I had success. But on first view it looks very well.

Comment: that was exactly what I was lookig for. Thank you :)

Comment: according to your post... my content is loaded in `webBrowser1` can I work with the content comming from there ? or do I have to make a total new instance from something? because I run through some login process and that could get a bit diffficult :D

Comment: You can use the `DocumentText` property of your `webBrowser1` to get the pages HTML then use the `HTMLDocuments` `LoadHtml` method and pass in the `DocumentText` :)